# The loop exits only after one of the iterator has reached the end. What is wrong here?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator

I have a simple for loop in c++

```
int makeAnagram(string a, string b)
{
  int deletionCnt = 0;
  sort(a.begin(), a.end());
  sort(b.begin(), b.end());

  string::iterator itrA = a.begin();
  string::iterator itrB = b.begin();

  for (itrA; (itrA != a.end() && itrB != b.end()); itrA++)
  {
    if (*itrA < *itrB)
    {
      deletionCnt++;
    }
    else if (*itrA == *itrB)
    {
      itrB++;
    }
    else if (*itrA > *itrB)
    {
      deletionCnt++;
      itrB++;
    }
    else if (itrA == a.end())
    {
      deletionCnt += (b.end() - itrB);
      itrB = b.end();
    }
    else if (itrB == b.end())
    {
      deletionCnt += (a.end() - itrA);
      itrA = a.end();
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Additional condition not checked : ";
    }
  }

  cout << "itrA is " << *itrA << ","
       << " itrB is " << *itrB << endl;
  return deletionCnt;
}
```

This loop does not run until both `itrA` and `itrB` reach their end, insteaad the loop ends when one of them reaches the end.

My understanding is that both the iterators should point to the end because that is the loop condition.

Can any one please explain about it ?

Thank you and cheers!

Comment: Provide a minimal complete program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The loop condition does exactly what it says. It will loop as long as both iterators are not at the end. Aka if one reaches the end, the condition is false and the loop exits.

Comment: change to ```!(itrA == a.end() && itrB == b.end())```

Comment: Be careful through, because if you change the loop condition so the loop continues when one iterator has reached the end, then dereferencing that iterator will lead to *undefined behavior*, and you need to check for that *before* you dereference the iterators in the first three `if` conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is functioning properly. The condition for loop termination is `itrA != a.end() && itrB != b.end()`. If either iterator has reached its end, the and clause will return false and the loop will terminate.

If you want the loop to terminate when both iterators are at their end, you could use a condition like `!(itrA == a.end() && itrA == a.end())`. Note that this will not work if you continue to move either iterator out of range.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `(itrA != a.end()` is true if itrA does **not** reach the end.

While `(itrA == a.end()` is true if itrA **does** reach the end.

The correct condition for both A and B reach the end is `(itrA == a.end() && itrB == b.end())`

Comment: This logic is applicable with `while` loop. How about `for` loop ?

Comment: I think `while` loop and `for` loop are semantically equivalent.